# method 'create' not found in app\user laravel 7

Tags: laravel

i'm trying to add registration to my laravel application, but i can't create a new user in my registration controller.actually the editor keep telling me that the create method not found
[the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivrVV.png)

and when i serve the application and try to create a user, this error appears: 
Class 'app\User' not found

[the error image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO3fE.png)
[the error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smy5B.png)

this is registration controller code:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use app\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function create() {
        return view('pages.register');
    }

    public function store() {

        $this->validate(request(), [
            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required'
        ]);
        **$user = User::create(request(['name', 'email', 'password']));**
        auth() -> login($user);

        return redirect() -> to('/');

    }

}
```

i couldn't find the issue for about a week. is there any way to correct this?
and i'm using Laravel Framework 7.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a "typo" when you provide a list of classes to use. While namespaces in PHP are case insensitive, when you are using Composer's autoload it stores classmap as associative array, where class name is used as a key, like this:

```
'App\\User' => $baseDir . '/app/User.php',
```

Keys of associative arrays are case sensitive, so when you use your class you must provide it's fully-qualified name in the same case as it was defined. Considering this, changing the case of namespace will fix the issue:

```
// Incorrect
use app\User;

// Correct
use App\User;
```

Comment: wow, that actually worked. thanks. but i don't know why, in my editor, the create method still can not be found. i mean the message in the first picture "the image here".anyway, i appreciate your help :3 thanks

Comment: Some methods like `create` doesn't really exists in `Model` class and loaded from another class using magic methods, so IDE can't resolve them. I suggest you to use [barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package to generate additional files for IDE, so it will be able to resolve these methods.

Comment: @Martin, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: thanks for your help, and i checked the acceptance mark. this was my first question in stackoverflow, i actually didn't see that at first :3

Answer (score 0):

The create method accepts an array. [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#inserts)

```
$user = User::create([
    'first_name' => 'Taylor',
    'last_name' => 'Otwell',
    'title' => 'Developer',
]);
```

In your case

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    .
    .
    $user = User::create($request->all());
    auth()->login($user, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this
    `use app\User;`
To this
    `use App\User;`